# HTML form post to PHP call using AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, forms

I'm trying to POST and email address entry from a HTML form to a PHP script to store the result in a database. The script is also responsible for firing an error message should the user enter an invalid email address etc. I would like the whole process to involve an AJAX call so that the page doesn't have to be reloaded each time that the user hits the submit button on the form.

As of now, each time the user hits the form submit button the page is being refreshed and i'm getting a response from the ajax call but it is immediately being written over due to the refresh.

Here's my HTML and Javascript/ajax:

```
<div id="emailform">
<form method="post"><!--action="planethome.php"-->
<input class="emailinput" type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" placeholder="enter your email address"/>
<input class="submitemailbutton" name="send_button" type="submit" value="Send" onClick="ajaxFunction()/>
<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="TRUE"/>
</form>
</div>

<div id="errororsuccess">
</div>


<!--ajax stuff:---------------------------------->


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
//Browser Support Code"
function ajaxFunction(){
    var ajaxRequest;  // The variable that makes Ajax possible!

    try{
        // Opera 8.0+, Firefox, Safari
        ajaxRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (e){
        // Internet Explorer Browsers
        try{
            ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (e) {
            try{
                ajaxRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (e){
                // Something went wrong
                alert("Ajax is struggling in your browser.");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    ajaxRequest.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if(ajaxRequest.readyState == 4){

            document.getElementById('errororsuccess').innerHTML = ajaxRequest.responseText;     

            }
    }

    // Create a function that will receive data sent from the server
    ajaxRequest.open("POST", "addemailtodatabase.php", true);
    ajaxRequest.send(null); 
}
```

and here's my PHP:

```
<?php

    require_once ('planetconfig.php');

    if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { /

        require_once (MYSQL);

        $email = FALSE;


        $trimmed = array_map('trim', $_POST);


        if (!empty($_POST['email'])) 
        {

            if (preg_match('/^[^0-9][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[@][a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/',$_POST['email'])) {

                $email = mysqli_real_escape_string ($dbc, $trimmed['email']);

            } else {
                echo "Invalid";         
            }

        } else {
                echo "You need to enter an email address";

        }


        if ($email) { 

            $q = "INSERT INTO planetemail (email, time) VALUES (AES_ENCRYPT('$email', 'password'), NOW())";

            $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q) or trigger_error("Query: $q\n<br />MySQL Error: " . mysqli_error($dbc));

            if (mysqli_affected_rows($dbc) == 1) { 

                echo "Thanks, we'll be in touch";

                exit();

            } else { 
                echo '<p class="error">We\'re sorry, something has gone wrong.</p>';
            }
        }

    mysqli_close($dbc);

} 
?>
```

I'm sure it's something to do with my POST method or how I have my ajax call set up.

I'm new to all this, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better implementation. I have a deadline of tomorrow morning to have this done.

Comment: that's awful. use jQuery

Comment: fancy elaborating on how it's awful rather than just stating that it is awful?

Comment: Crikey, I used to be awful! Update - if anyone is reading this, disregard everything that I have written and use jQuery for the AJAX and it'd probably make your life easier to use a web application framework of some sort for the back end instead of writing grotty PHP like I did. I recommend CodeIgniter for beginners.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're problem is that you are using a submit button.  The submit button will submit the form, change it from a type="submit" to type="button" and it will work and as @juzerali suggested, use jQuery, that code hurts my head.

Comment: Use jQuery for the whole Ajax part you mean? Thanks for your input, I think the form submit type is the problem

Comment: The button submit type is the problem, but overall, jQuery makes ajax so much easier, and gives you so much more, you really should look into using it.  It's also great on your resume since so many employers want it (even though most have no idea what it is)

Comment: great yeah, i'll sort that now

Comment: i'm going to have some dinner, fix it and then mark as correct (hopefully!)

Comment: Took your advice and jQuery is awesome.

Answer (score 2):

1st, yes that is awful, use jquery. 2nd although you have bound ajax call with onclick of submit button, you have not prevented the default behaviour from executing. The form will still get submitted the usual way.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) { /
```

There is a stray / in your code.

Also, Change type="submit" to type="button"

The onClick event handler will pick up the submit becuase you are making an AJAX request, no need to POST.

Comment: Unsure what you mean by stray?

Comment: the slash at the end of that line doesnt belong there. its causing a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

`return false;` at the end of the script to keep it from submitting the normal way.